# Extracting strings from regular expression Python

Tags: python

I am using Python and trying to understand how to use regular expressions.
I have a list of strings like this:

```
example = ['(string1)-(hello)', '(string2)-(world)']
```

where I have 2 strings closed by parentheses separated by anything, so I am only interested in what is inside the (). I would like to obtain a list of strings:

```
example = ['string1', 'hello', 'string2' , 'world']
```

Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: Iterate on the list, for each item, `\(.*?\)` is what you're looking for.

Comment: You could also have a look at the docs for re. [this example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs) might suit you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `re.findall` function along with list_comprehension.

```
>>> example = ['(string1)-(hello)', '(string2)-(world)']
>>> [x for i in example for x in re.findall(r'\(([^\)]*)\)', i)]
['string1', 'hello', 'string2', 'world']
```

Comment: Excellent compact and readable working example. Although I would perform a `re.compile` beforehand, as the performance increases and I find it a little more readable.

Comment: @MariusSiuram Readable maybe, but don't make claims about performance until you've timed them: Python already caches regular expressions and in fact using `timeit` I find that `python -m timeit -s "import re" -s "example = ['(string1)-(hello)', '(string2)-(world)']" -s "regex = re.compile(r'\(([^\)]*)\)')" "[x for i in example for x in re.findall(regex, i)]"` is actually slower than `python -m timeit -s "import re" -s "example = ['(string1)-(hello)', '(string2)-(world)']" "[x for i in example for x in re.findall(r'\(([^\)]*)\)', i)]"`

Comment: I made claims about performance because I had just done them :)

Comment: Disclaimer: well, of course I am expecting a big reusability or a big list. Otherwise it simply doesn't matter.